# Can a matrix have partial derivatives?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Consider a 2 dimensional matrix $A$ with dimensions $n \times n$.

Can I calculate the partial derivatives of this matrix?
i.e. $\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}$.

Obviously using finite differences, but I want to know whether it's correct to calculate partial derivatives of a matrix.

Thanks.

Comment: A matrix over what?

Comment: What do you mean by asking a matrix over what?

Comment: In other words, what are the entries of the matrix?

Comment: Discrete numbers.

Comment: How can you take the derivative of a number?

Comment: That's why I'm asking if it makes sense to use finite differences. The matrix $A$ is an image, but an image can be thought of as a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I want to calculate the gradient of $A$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61934/discussion-between-gfauxpas-and-gina).

Answer (score 1):

Sure. After all, you can think of a matrix as a vector, or better vector valued function, with length $n^2$. Then proceed taking partial derivatives as you would for a vector field.